# jquery - Add exception onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following input fields:

```
<input type="text" value="5" maxlength="12" id="qty" class="input-text qty" name="qty2050" tabindex="1">
```

and

```
<input type="text" value="0" maxlength="12" id="qty" class="input-text qty" name="qty2042" tabindex="1">
```

I use this code to prevent the user from losing inserted data (upon quitting the page):

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var showAlert = false;
    jQuery('.input-text.qty').each(function (){

        //console.log("fonction 1");
        var val = parseInt(jQuery(this).val(),10);
        if(val > 0) { showAlert = true; } 
        //alert(val);
    });

    //console.log("fonction 2");
    //console.log(showAlert);

    if (showAlert == true) {
        console.log("fonction 3");
        return 'You have unsaved changes!';
    } 
}

</script>
```

I want to add an exception to my submit button, and to not show the alert message when there is a quantity > 0 in one of my input fields.

My problem is in adding this exception!

Thanks for help.

Comment: Perhaps provide a little more information on what you want help with?

Comment: I have edited my question, I hope it's more clear now...

Comment: What do you mean by quantity > 0, what alert are you talking about, maybe try clearing up your question...

Comment: quantity > 0 means that the user have entered a quantity, in this case it's greater that 0; This test is aleready done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bool confirmUnload. Like here: http://jonstjohn.com/node/23

```
<script>
var confirmUnload = true;

$("submit").click(function(){ confirmUnload = false; });

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (confirmUnload)
    {
        var showAlert = false;
        jQuery('.input-text.qty').each(function (){

            //console.log("fonction 1");
            var val = parseInt(jQuery(this).val(),10);
            if(val > 0) { showAlert = true; } 
            //alert(val);
        });

        //console.log("fonction 2");
        //console.log(showAlert);

        if (showAlert == true) {
            console.log("fonction 3");
            return 'You have unsaved changes!';
        }
    } 
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but in seems that this portion o code 
`$("submit").click(function(){ confirmUnload = false; });`
isn't running

I have also added `confirmUnload = false;` direct to my button (onclick) but it also don't works :(

Comment: It's OK, I have added it to my form (onsubmit) nd it works now.
Thanks a lot or help :)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you  want:

```
<SCRIPT> 
function checkForm(e) { 
   if (!(window.confirm("Do you want to submit the form?"))) 
     e.returnValue = false; 
 } 
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM name="theForm" action="0801.html" 
   onSubmit = "return checkForm(event)">
<INPUT type=submit>
</FORM>
```

your checks will go into the checkForm method in this case

Comment: Yes, but how can I adapt my code to do the same function ? I'm still in the beginning of jquery development... Thanks